# Vue.js Property or method "vehicles" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Absolute beginner at Vue & php, started working on a [tutorial](https://hackthestuff.com/article/laravel-8-crud-using-vuejs-with-example). Everything works except I get the mentioned error when retrieving **vehicles**.

I messed around, and afaik it's not the API call (going to localhost:8000/api/vehicles results in the table being shown properly.)

Relevant(?) Code: (if more is needed, comment)

AllVehicles.vue

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <h2 class="text-center">Vehicles List</h2>

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Make</th>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Mileage</th>
                <th>VIN</th>
                <!-- <th>Actions</th> -->
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr v-for="vehicle in this.vehicles" :key="vehicle.vid">
                <td>{{ vehicle.vid }}</td>
                <td>{{ vehicle.make }}</td>
                <td>{{ vehicle.model }}</td>
                <td>{{ vehicle.year }}</td>
                <td>{{ vehicle.mileage }}</td>
                <td>{{ vehicle.VIN }}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        {/*<router-link :to="{name: 'edit', params: { id: vehicle.vid }}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</router-link>*/}
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="deleteVehicle(vehicle.vid)">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script >
    export default {
        data: {
            vehicles: []
        },
        created() {
            this.axios
                .get('http://localhost:8000/api/vehicles/')
                .then(response => {
                    this.vehicles = response.data;
                    console.log(this.vehicles);
                });
        },
        methods: {
            deleteVehicle(vid) {
                this.axios
                    .delete(`http://localhost:8000/api/vehicles/${vid}`)
                    .then(response => {
                        let i = this.vehicles.map(data => data.vid).indexOf(vid);
                        this.vehicles.splice(i, 1)
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

app.js

```
    /**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';

require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = Vue;

import App from './App.vue';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import axios from 'axios';
import { routes } from './routes';

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        vehicles: []
    },
    router: router,
    render: h => h(App),
});
```

routes.js

```
import AllVehicles from './components/AllVehicles.vue';

export const routes = [{
    name: 'home',
    path: '/',
    component: AllVehicles
}];
```

I have noticed specifically the error is coming from `<tr v-for="vehicle in this.vehicles" :key"vehicle.vid">` (regardless of using `this.` or not) which leads me to suspect it's not seeing the `vehicles` defined in the data segment below. Unfortunately I have absolutely no clue what's going on here.

Comment: `data` should be a function, so try `data() {return {vehicles: []} }`

Comment: @aynber changed, to no avail. as mentioned in another comment, I don't think anything between the `<script>` tags are being ran (no console.log prints are printed to the console. Not sure what to do about this or if it's normal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This portion if your code is what is giving you the error

```
<tr v-for="vehicle in this.vehicles" :key="vehicle.vid">
                <td>{{ vehicle.vid }}</td>
                <td>{{ vehicle.make }}</td>
                <td>{{ vehicle.model }}</td>
                <td>{{ vehicle.year }}</td>
                <td>{{ vehicle.mileage }}</td>
                <td>{{ vehicle.VIN }}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        {/*<router-link :to="{name: 'edit', params: { id: vehicle.vid }}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</router-link>*/}
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="deleteVehicle(vehicle.vid)">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Because it is assumed that you have a data `this` which is an object with `vehicles` in it referenced by `this.vehicles`. Since vehicle does not exist, it is assumed you are looping through a non-existent value.

In the template, you do not need `this`. So the right code will be

```
<tr v-for="vehicle in vehicles" :key="vehicle.vid">
                <td>{{ vehicle.vid }}</td>
                <td>{{ vehicle.make }}</td>
                <td>{{ vehicle.model }}</td>
                <td>{{ vehicle.year }}</td>
                <td>{{ vehicle.mileage }}</td>
                <td>{{ vehicle.VIN }}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        {/*<router-link :to="{name: 'edit', params: { id: vehicle.vid }}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</router-link>*/}
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="deleteVehicle(vehicle.vid)">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Check below for an example of such use case for vue 2 documentation.

[https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#:~:text=%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22app-4,text%3A%20%27Build%20something%20awesome%27%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#:%7E:text=%3Cdiv%20id%3D%22app-4,text%3A%20%27Build%20something%20awesome%27%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D))

Also you would have to remove data `vehicles` from `app.js`

Comment: yeah, I had a feeling this.vehicles would be improper there. however, that change (and the one to app.js) did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your app.js is wrong declarate the data, you should only declarate the '#app' div where is your application main component.

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    render: h => h(App),
});
```

in your component AllVehicles you change the data :

```
name:'AllVehicles',
    data() {
        return {
            vehicles: [],
        };
    },


created() {
            this.axios
                .get('http://localhost:8000/api/vehicles/')
                .then(response => {
                    this.vehicles = response.data;
                    console.log(this.vehicles);
                });
        },
```

after this change on your console you should execute: `npm run dev` to update the changes.

Comment: This unfortunately did not fix the issue. Still getting the same error. To that same end, while it's on my mind: the `console.log(this.vehicles)` also doesn't print to the console at all. Is my <script> section just not running? that would explain why the frontend portion doesn't see `vehicles` but not sure how to debug that. (edit: also changed this.vehicles => vehicles inside of the tr)

Comment: i will recommend you put on your browser Chrome the Vue.js devtools extension for do a debug of the objects through the frontent console.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out in Atom (likely incorrectly set up by me) when it recognizes your `.vue` files as "Babel ES6 Javascript" your `<script></script>` tags will go from

```
<script>
   stuff
</script>
```

to

```
<
script>
   stuff
</script>
```

which (guessing) makes Vue/Laravel/whatever have an absolute heart-attack and won't run the code.